# How to display 6 items in 2 rows horizontally equidistant in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm writing a catalog app for Android tablet, which displays 6 item per page: 3 items for each row.
Each item is composed by an image (200x300) and a text.
Designing with android xml layout editor in Eclipse everything seems fine, because I'm using a default image for each item and a dummy fixed text: each item is horizontally perfectly equidistant there.

When I run on tablet, each item is overwritten with an image taken from filesystem (200x300 again) and the text (variable length) is taken from database.
The problem is taht after the 6 elements are populated with my custom data, the layout seems disaligned, as you can see from this screenshot: [image: http://postimg.org/image/91mcv0z1f/]

Probably (but I'm not sure) the problem is caused by the long text.
Is there a way (if the problem is the text) to force the layout to remain fixed? (Or make the font small dinamically (or trunc the text, I don't care))

This is the layout I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RootView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filaTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBottle1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottle1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="vino"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBottle2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottle2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="vino"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBottle3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottle3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="vino"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filaBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBottle4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottle4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="vino"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBottle5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottle5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="vino"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBottle6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottle6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="vino"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (SOLVED):** putting `android:layout_width="0dip"` in each linear layout, solved the problem as Dale Wilson suggested, like this:

> ```
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="0dip"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
> ```

Comment: Maybe you can try GridLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have layout_weight, start the views at 0px.  The layout_weight will grow them all to the same size.   If you say wrap_content then they start at different sizes, grow the same amounts, so they end up with different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Update your layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:id="@+id/RootView">


    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/filaTop">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBottle1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBottle1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="vino"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="22sp" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/ivBottle2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

            <TextView
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/tvBottle2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="vino"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="22sp" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/ivBottle3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

            <TextView
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/tvBottle3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="vino"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="22sp" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/filaBottom">


         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBottle4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBottle4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="vino"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="22sp" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/ivBottle5"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

            <TextView
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/tvBottle5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="vino"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="22sp" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/ivBottle6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bottle_trans" />

            <TextView
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/tvBottle6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="vino"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="22sp" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Also remove unnecessary lines of code.